# JSONata string manipulation at a specific point

Tags: jsonata

Given array like this

```
$s := [
"aString 1",
"bString",
"test",
"test 2",
"window 1",
"window 2",
"Garage",
"Sport",
"cString",
"etc"
]
```

I need a string with the comma-separated array elements.
However, the total length of the substring must not exceed 30. At these points, instead of the comma, a semicolon must be used.

With a simple

```
$s ~> $join(',')
```

i get

```
"aString 1,bString,test,test 2,window 1,window 2,Garage,Sport,cString,etc"
```

Here the 4th and the 7th comma must be replaced by a semicolon, because otherwise the sections are >= 30 like so

```
"aString 1,bString,test,test 2;window 1,window 2,Garage;Sport,cString,etc"
```

Is there a possibility with the JSONata string functions?

I have tried with a $map() function like this:

```
(
$result := "";
 
$map($s , function($v){
      $result := $result & $v & ($length($result) < 30 ? ',' : ';')
});
)
```

But this does not work. The manipulation of $result only works within the function.
How could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You use $reduce in order to transform the array to a string. The reduce operation concatenates the string. The trick is to reduce not only to a string, but an object that contains a length counter and the concatenated result:

```
{
  "count": chars since the last ;
  "result": the concatenated string
}
```

Here's the expression:

```
(
    /* initial reduce value: count 0 with empty string */
    $init := {
        "count": 0,
        "result": ""
    };
    /* $ is the input array */
    $reduce($, function($i, $j){
        /* $i is the count / result object, $j is the current array string */ 
        $i.count + 1 + $length($j) >= 30 ?
            /* too long, use ; and reset the length */
            {
                "count": $length($j),
                "result": $i.result & ";" & $j
            }
        :
            $i.count = 0 ? 
                /* happens only in the very beginning, avoid leading , */
                {
                    "count": $length($j),
                    "result": $j
                }
            :
                /* append using , */
                {
                    "count": $i.count + 1 + $length($j),
                    "result": $i.result & "," & $j
                }
    }, $init);
).result
```